# how can i extend a beveled object in a different direction?

Tags: edit-mode, bevel

I have a beveled object (the molding on a wall) and I want to take the | shape that its in and make it into an L shape to fit an L shaped wall. I have tried so many things and I'm just dumbfounded at this point. how can I do this?

[here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Ur0i_QMb0KkTQutz8XeHi9oczaxIf6x/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with curve:

Create your L shape, to have an orthogonal shape, select your curve vertices, press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Vector*. Create the profile you want with a second curve. Select your first curve and in the *Object Data* panel > *Geometry* > *Bevel* > enable *Object* and *Object* > select your second curve:

[image]

Comment: how do i get the end of my curve to connect to the beginning to complete the L shape?

Comment: select the tip vertices and press F (fill)